Search for an odd positive minimum
Please help me understand what the error is. Here are the conditions of the problem:

Print the value of the smallest positive odd element of the array, and
if there are no positive odd elements in the array, print the number
0.
Input data format
In the first line, enter the number of elements in the array. The
array elements are entered in the second line.
Output data format
Print the answer to the problem.
Sample Input:\
9
-231 -97 13 41 9 -22 46 17 12
Sample Output:
9

Here is my code (it works, but the site says that the task was solved incorrectly):
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Scanner dashka = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = dashka.nextInt();
        int[] a = new int[n];
        int min = 0;
        int y = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            a[i] = dashka.nextInt();
            if (i == y && a[i] > 0) {
                min = a[i];
            }
            else if ((a[i] == 0 || a[i] < 0) && i % 2 != 0) {
                y += 2;
            }
            if (i % 2 == 0 && a[i] > 0) {
                if (a[i] < min) {
                    min = a[i];
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.print(min);
    }
}

I kind of checked all the input options, and now I'm at a dead end because I can't find the error.

Were t doing this, the first thing I'd write is a function public static boolean isPositiveAndOdd(int n). It might seem over the top but it will make your coding a lot easier and clearer. continue is also your friend

First there may be confusion as to what is being asked.

Print the value of the smallest positive odd element of the array, and if there are no positive odd elements in the array, print the number 0.

You are taking the first sentence to mean the element at the odd index. Hence your remainder tests for i instead of a[i].  I believe this to be incorrect although I could be wrong.  I believe the task wants a[i] to be odd.  One reason I believe this are the adjectives used.  Array indices can only be positive so extra verbage would be needed to distinguish between odd indices and positive elements.  When checking for odd do if (a[i] % 2 == 1) {...}
I recommend the following changes.
You are doing a number of things wrong as well that has code is not really needed.

I don't see a need for y or any of the code that uses or references y so remove it.
Set min to Integer.MAX_VALUE. If you initialize it to 0, no positive value will be less than 0 when testing the array, so you would return 0 as the result.
Use a boolean flag, foundOne to determine whether to return 0 or the default min.

Putting it all together
Scanner dashka = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = dashka.nextInt();
int[] a = new int[n];
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
boolean foundOne = false;
//int y = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    a[i] = dashka.nextInt();
//    if (i == y && a[i] > 0) {
//        min = a[i];
//    }
//    else if ((a[i] == 0 || a[i] < 0) && i % 2 != 0) {
//        y += 2;
//    }
    if (a[i] % 2 == 1 && a[i] > 0) {
        if (a[i] <= min) {
            min = a[i];
            foundOne = true;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(foundOne ? min : 0);

When input is taken from the console, you don't need an array and can just process the values as they are read.  If the data is presented in an initialized array you may want to put this in a method which takes an array and returns the smallest, positive, odd integer.
public static int findSmallestPostiveOdd(int[] arr) {
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    boolean foundOne = false;
    for (int val : arr) {
        if (val >= 1 && val % 2 == 1 && val <= min) {
            min = val;
            foundOne = true;
        }
    }
    return foundOne ? min : 0;
}

Note, if I am incorrect about what odd means then the easiest solution, imo, is to modify the last method shown above and simply iterate across the array as follows and remove the remainder(%) tests for parity.
for (int i = 1; i <arr.length; i+=2) {
     int val = arr[i];
...
...

} 


+1, though I think I disagree with the suggestion to create int findSmallestPostiveOdd(int[] arr), because honestly, there's no reason to even create an array here. (Note that for any given i, a[i] is only ever used in the same loop iteration where it was set. So it can just be a variable element declared inside the loop.)

@ruakh  I agree entirely.  The values could be processed as they are read from the console and avoid a second iteration.  But the first sentence of the problem statement did mention an array so I included the method for demo.  I'll modify my answer and caveate it.

The task is strigt forward.

Read numbers from the console one by one;
Filter out negatives and even;
Compare with current min and choose the minimum between two values.

public class Main {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int min = 0;
        int total = scan.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
            int num = scan.nextInt();

            if (isPositive(num) && isOdd(num))
                min = min == 0 ? num : Math.min(min, num);
        }

        System.out.println(min);
    }

    private static boolean isPositive(int num) {
        return num > 0;
    }

    private static boolean isOdd(int num) {
        return (num & 1) != 0;
    }

}

